Dependabot on GitLab can not find file or directory error
I'm trying to integrate dependabot on a project that is on GitLab.
I followed the official doc or even another doc.
https://gitlab.com/dependabot-gitlab/dependabot-standalone
https://kkurko.hashnode.dev/keep-your-dependencies-up-to-date-with-dependabot-on-gitlab#heading-create-github-personal-access-token
On both, I can launch a dependabot job but I still get the same error
[2024-04-26 09:03:30 +0000] INFO  -- [dep-update: XX/services/XX=>composer] Fetching configuration file .gitlab/dependabot.yml from branch master for project XX/services/XX
[2024-04-26 09:03:31 +0000] INFO  -- [dep-update: XX/services/XX=>composer] Fetching vulnerability data from GitHub advisory database
[2024-04-26 09:03:31 +0000] INFO  -- [dep-update: XX/services/XX=>composer]   fetching COMPOSER vulnerabilities
[2024-04-26 09:04:21 +0000] INFO  -- [dep-update: XX/services/XX=>composer]   fetched 6250 vulnerabilities
[2024-04-26 09:04:30 +0000] INFO  -- [dep-update: XX/services/XX=>composer] Processing dependency beberlei/doctrineextensions
[2024-04-26 09:04:30 +0000] ERROR -- [dep-update: XX/services/XX=>composer] No such file or directory - php
[2024-04-26 09:04:30 +0000] ERROR -- [dep-update: XX/services/XX=>composer] /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/open3.rb:222:in `spawn'

dependabot.yml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: composer
    directory: /
    commit-message:
      prefix: chore
    schedule:
      interval: daily
      time: '07:00'
      timezone: Europe/Paris
    open-pull-requests-limit: 1
    ignore:
      - dependency-name: symfony/* # Empêche de passer en Symfony 7
        versions: ['>=6.5']

The pipeline schedule configuration

I don't understand this error.

Maybe you should paste all the code here
